# Close Transparent Activity by calling onDestroy/ Lifecycle of Transparent Activity

Tags: android, transparent, lifecycle, activity-finish, ondestroy

I have simple code with transparent activity (it is imposed on my MainActivity). I need to kill this transparent activity by clicking button and after that I need to show dialog. But get some problems first of all if I do that :

```
public void buttonClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.bToK)
    {
        onDestroy();
    }
}
```

transparent activity it's still visible just nothing happen (in debug mode I see that it goes to onDestroy but I doesn't destroy it at all)
If I change onDestron() to finish() there are other problems because my Main activity became first visible (onResume is called) then called is onDestroy for transparent what provides to next problems during creating this dialog. What should I do If i want show this dialog after kill this transparent ?

Answer (score 0):

Call finish() instead. This will call onDestroy() and respect the activity life. Next if you want open a dialog you can start it before finish or start in the main activity with onResult https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Calm down ! I edit my post and if you use onResult you can wait the dialog to close to finish the activity. Or you can stop the "transparent" activity with response code to the main activity which will open the dialog

Comment: How I can start my dialog exactly after kill TransparentActivity ? or before onResume MainActivity ?

Comment: You have to start your transparent activity from the main with startActivityForResult and when you call finifh() the onresult (in MainActivity) will be call by the system start your dialog here. Read the doc i gave you in my answer